# Android-Kernel: Is there any way to dump ftrace to a file when kernel panic occurs

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, android-kernel

I write all my module's logs to ftrace., and could not get my log prior to kernel panic occurs. Is there any way/trick to dump the entire /d/tracing/trace into a file when kernel panic occurs? 
enabled all ftrace related configs and tried with,

```
 "echo -n 0x1 > /proc/sys/kernel/ftrace_dump_on_oops"
```

But didn't work. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you enabled any tracer in the kernel configuration?

Comment: @Andy,Yes. I have all of them enabled them.

Comment: Why not use the console(Ex. UART)? Its the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to console, you may try using `ramoops` mechanism (Documentation/ramoops.txt) combined with `ftrace_dump_on_oops` you mentioned together with `pstore`. Alternatively you can use `mtdoops` (drivers/mtd/mtdoops.c) if `ramoops` won't work for you.